# Lebesgue measure of $\mathcal{D}_{q_2}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A set defined by $$\mathcal{D}_{q_2}=\left\{a\in[0,1]:\frac{q_1-A^{-1}}{q_2}<a<\frac{q_1+A^{-1}}{q_2},0\leqslant q_1\leqslant q_2\right\}.$$ I don't known whether its Lebesgue measure is $2A^{-1}$ or $\dfrac{2A^{-1}}{q_2}$. Assume $[q_1-A^{-1},q_1+A^{-1}]\subseteq [0,1]$ and $q_1$ is fixed. Please show me the reason.

Comment: Is $q_1$ a fixed number?

Comment: Is it possible to have $A^{-1} \gt q_1$ or $A^{-1} \gt q_2-q_1$?  If not, then you can use$\frac{q_1+A^{-1}}{q_2} - \frac{q_1-A^{-1}}{q_2}= \frac{2A^{-1}}{q_2}$.  But if $A^{-1}$ is too big then there are other possible answers

Comment: Please tell what $q_1,q_2$ and $A$ are! Are they fixed? Which ones are fixed? Can they take several values, if yes, which ones?